# angular app errors upon back button click from 3rd party website

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

when i click back button from any 3rd party web site to go back to my angular app, I see lots of console errors and my angular app fails to load.

Uncaught TypeError: no access
    at :10:29
    at :58:5
...
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

I tried few apps showcased at https://www.madewithangular.com/ and I see the same problem with them.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. open an angular app in browser. keep the console open to see the errors.
2. now visit a 3rd party website like google.com in the same tab.
3. click back button to go back to the angular app.

Is it a known problem ? Any suggestions to fix this problem ?

Thanks.

Update:

1. go to http://embed.plnkr.co/d8Fb7o8OjUFdXOLKAaS7/
2. now visit google.com in the same tab.
3. click back button.

the app does not load. Please open chrome console to see the errors.

Thank you

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem. When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @georgeawg : Hi. I have provided a plunkr. Hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: The problem occurs when switching from `http://plnkr.com` to `https://plnkr.com`. `<script>` tags that source `http:` protocol violate [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and are blocked by the browser.